# I can't sign out with google's signOut() method - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-signin

I'm trying to implement Google's sign in and sign out methods. Altough sign in works perfectly signout method gives this error:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient.signOut()' on a null object reference`

Also i just copied and pasted the code from google's site:

```
private void signOut() {
    mGoogleSignInClient.signOut()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    Toast.makeText(signup.this,"user signed out",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it via extracting GoogleSignInOptions from if else block.